# Oracle count statement problem

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Hope someone can help with a problem I'm having with building a query in oracle.

I'm a newbie to oracle, allthough i do have some little knowledge of sql -

It's a cinema booking system scenario - and Im trying to get the sql below to output one line, which is a total of the tickets sold for a particular performance in a particular cinema. I have got as far as below, allthough it lists all 12 occurances, when I want it to say 12 tickets sold etc.

I built this up initally in query builder, then added the count and group by manualy.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated as to how i could achieve this, or where i may be going wrong.

Thanks for looking.

```
select count(ticket.ticket_id) as tickets_sold, "PERFORMANCE"."PERFORMANCE_DATE" as "PERFORMANCE_DATE",
     "FILM"."FILM_TITLE" as "FILM_TITLE",
     "TICKET"."TICKET_ID" as "TICKET_ID",
     "CINEMA"."LOCATION" as "LOCATION",
     "PERFORMANCE"."PERFORMANCE_TIME" as "PERFORMANCE_TIME" 
 from    "TICKET" "TICKET",
     "RESERVATION" "RESERVATION",
     "PERFORMANCE" "PERFORMANCE",
     "RUN" "RUN",
     "SCREEN" "SCREEN",
     "CINEMA" "CINEMA",
     "FILM" "FILM" 
 where   "PERFORMANCE"."PERFORMANCE_ID"="RESERVATION"."PERFORMANCE_ID"
 and     "PERFORMANCE"."RUN_ID"="RUN"."RUN_ID"
 and     "RUN"."FILM_ID"="FILM"."FILM_ID"
 and     "RUN"."SCREEN_ID"="SCREEN"."SCREEN_ID"
 and     "SCREEN"."CINEMA_ID"="CINEMA"."CINEMA_ID"
 and     "TICKET"."RESERVATION_ID"="RESERVATION"."RESERVATION_ID"
  and    "PERFORMANCE"."PERFORMANCE_DATE" ='1-mar-09' 
   and   "FILM"."FILM_TITLE" ='PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END' 
   and   "CINEMA"."LOCATION" ='bradfordeast' 
   and   "PERFORMANCE"."PERFORMANCE_TIME" ='20:00' group by reservation.performance_id, performance.performance_date, film.film_title, ticket.ticket_id,cinema.location, performance.performance_time order by tickets_sold DESC;
```

output:

```
TICKETS_SOLD PERFORMANCE_DATE FILM_TITLE TICKET_ID LOCATION PERFORMANCE_TIME 

1 01-MAR-09 PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END 485 bradfordeast 20:00

1 01-MAR-09 PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END 488 bradfordeast 20:00

1 01-MAR-09 PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END 484 bradfordeast 20:00 

1 01-MAR-09 PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END 491 bradfordeast 20:00

1 01-MAR-09 PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END 493 bradfordeast 20:00 

1 01-MAR-09 PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END 495 bradfordeast 20:00

1 01-MAR-09 PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END 489 bradfordeast 20:00

1 01-MAR-09 PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END 487 bradfordeast 20:00 

1 01-MAR-09 PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END 490 bradfordeast 20:00 

1 01-MAR-09 PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END 492 bradfordeast 20:00 

1 01-MAR-09 PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END 494 bradfordeast 20:00 

1 01-MAR-09 PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END 486 bradfordeast 20:00
```

Comment: thanks for editing the format :) much easier to understand now !

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to include both `ticket_id` and `COUNT(ticket_id)` when you `GROUP BY ticket_id`.

I infer that your schema has relationships something like the following:

```
TICKETS --> RESERVATION --> PERFORMANCE --> RUN --> SCREEN --> CINEMA
                                   FILM --> RUN
```

It looks like your desired report could be described as the following:

> Count tickets per film, performance date & time, and cinema location.

It's important in any query using `GROUP BY` that the columns in your `SELECT`-list match the columns in your `GROUP BY` list (except for columns inside aggregate functions such as `COUNT()`).  This is called the **Single-Value Rule**, and it's enforced in standard SQL.  These would be the columns following "per" in the report description.

Here's how I'd write the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(t."TICKET_ID") AS tickets_sold, 
 f."FILM_TITLE",
 c."LOCATION",
 p."PERFORMANCE_DATE",
 p."PERFORMANCE_TIME",
FROM "TICKET" t,
 JOIN "RESERVATION" r ON (r."RESERVATION_ID" = t."RESERVATION_ID") 
 JOIN "PERFORMANCE" p ON (p."PERFORMANCE_ID" = r."PERFORMANCE_ID")
 JOIN "RUN" run ON (run."RUN_ID" = p."RUN_ID")
 JOIN "SCREEN" s ON (s."SCREEN_ID" = run."SCREEN_ID")
 JOIN "CINEMA" c ON (c."CINEMA_ID" = s."CINEMA_ID")
 JOIN "FILM" f ON (f."FILM_ID" = run."FILM_ID")
WHERE p."PERFORMANCE_DATE" ='1-mar-09'
 AND f."FILM_TITLE" ='PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END' 
 AND c."LOCATION" ='bradfordeast' 
 AND p."PERFORMANCE_TIME" ='20:00'
GROUP BY f."FILM_TITLE", c."LOCATION", p."PERFORMANCE_DATE", p."PERFORMANCE_TIME" 
ORDER BY tickets_sold DESC;
```

Note that I used standard `JOIN` syntax, moving the join conditions into `ON` clauses.  The `WHERE` clause includes only query restrictions.  Logically, there's no difference in the result of the query, but for the sake of clarity, I prefer to keep join conditions close to the respective tables in the `FROM` clause.

I also used single-letter table aliases to keep things more readable (except `r` versus `run` because they both start with r).

Comment: that looks great - I have had a look at this, however I keep getting oro00936, missing expression - I have studied the script and it all looks good to me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need exclude "ticket.ticket_id" from group clause (this unique value making unnecessary groups - result strings):

```
select count(ticket.ticket_id) as tickets_sold, "PERFORMANCE"."PERFORMANCE_DATE" as "PERFORMANCE_DATE",
         "FILM"."FILM_TITLE" as "FILM_TITLE",
         "TICKET"."TICKET_ID" as "TICKET_ID",
         "CINEMA"."LOCATION" as "LOCATION",
         "PERFORMANCE"."PERFORMANCE_TIME" as "PERFORMANCE_TIME" 
     from    "TICKET" "TICKET",
         "RESERVATION" "RESERVATION",
         "PERFORMANCE" "PERFORMANCE",
         "RUN" "RUN",
         "SCREEN" "SCREEN",
         "CINEMA" "CINEMA",
         "FILM" "FILM" 
     where   "PERFORMANCE"."PERFORMANCE_ID"="RESERVATION"."PERFORMANCE_ID"
     and     "PERFORMANCE"."RUN_ID"="RUN"."RUN_ID"
     and     "RUN"."FILM_ID"="FILM"."FILM_ID"
     and     "RUN"."SCREEN_ID"="SCREEN"."SCREEN_ID"
     and     "SCREEN"."CINEMA_ID"="CINEMA"."CINEMA_ID"
     and     "TICKET"."RESERVATION_ID"="RESERVATION"."RESERVATION_ID"
      and    "PERFORMANCE"."PERFORMANCE_DATE" ='1-mar-09' 
       and   "FILM"."FILM_TITLE" ='PIRATES OF THE CARIBBEAN - AT WORLDS END' 
       and   "CINEMA"."LOCATION" ='bradfordeast' 
       and   "PERFORMANCE"."PERFORMANCE_TIME" ='20:00'
group by reservation.performance_id, performance.performance_date,
film.film_title, ticket.ticket_id,cinema.location, performance.performance_time
order by tickets_sold DESC;
```

Comment: and from "select" clause too!

Comment: hi - thanks for the comment, i tryed something similar earlier - just tried again - along the lines of what you said and the same error came up - ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression. this doesn't show when the tick.ticket_id is n the group by - thanks

Comment: you need exclude "ticket.ticket_id" from "group by" clause, and from "select" clause too ("TICKET"."TICKET_ID" as "TICKET_ID"). and thats will be good. unfortunately, i can`t edit my answer ( and i wrote bad comment

Comment: all looks good  - I understand why it was not working now - thanks! not sure how to mark this as answered - or if i need to ? - first time on here.